How to Fade Background Images when changing image
As part of my learning, I have manage to set the background image of my page and change the image every 10 seconds.
However, the change between images is harsh with a white background shown before the next image.  Is there anyway I can fade each image in/out?    All help will be appreciated.

  * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  
  html { 
    background: url(/cover1.webp) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }

</style>

<div class="hero is-fullheight">

</div>
<script>
  function changeBg(){
    const images = [
      'url("/cover1.webp")',      'url("/cover2.webp")',      'url("/cover3.webp")',      'url("/cover4.webp")',
      'url("/cover5.webp")',      'url("/cover6.webp")',      'url("/cover7.webp")',      'url("/cover8.webp")',
      'url("/cover9.webp")',      'url("/covera.webp")',      'url("/coverb.webp")',      'url("/coverc.webp")',
    ]

    const selector = document.querySelector('html');
    const bg = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
    selector.style.backgroundImage = bg;
  }
  setInterval(changeBg, 10000)
</script>


You could pre-load all your images (in hidden <img> tags) so that they are cached and thus do not need to load from the server each time (which is the white flash while loading).  Disclaimer: I've not actually checked if <img> src is cached for reuse with .backgroundImage.  If not, then have some  hidden divs and set their background - this should cache the image.

Optimise the images so they take less time to load

This probably answers your question: how can I fade in a background image

That got it :-).    Simply change to the html style tag and all working....     Will update the question with what I used.

Does this answer your question? Can I fade in a background image (CSS: background-image) with jQuery?

Just changing the html style tag produced the effect I wanted:
  html { 
    background: url(/cover1.webp) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out 1000ms;
    -moz-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out 1000ms;
    -o-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out 1000ms;
    transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out 1000ms;
  }


You can add animation properties to your images. For example if you have images with class "image".
CSS
.image {
  animation: fade 1s ease-in-out;
  @keyframes fade {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
  }
}

